Flyback output capacitors and extremely high RMS current
I'm designing a DCM flyback converter for the first time and I've encountered a problem where the RMS current through the output capacitors reaches 5.6A. I started looking for suitable capacitors, and found capacitor UPW1V152MHD6 - 35V, low ESR, 1.5mF, maximum RMS 2.51A. To cover the RMS current with a margin, I need to put them 3pcs in parallel. However, this means an output capacitance of 4.5mF which seems extremely high to me, I've never seen a flyback with such an output capacitance. I couldn't find any electrolytic capacitors with the same RMS current but lower capacitance (tme.eu). I found a reference design of a similar power supply, but the manufacturer put a 35V, low ESR, 470uF, maximum RMS 1.5A capacitor on the output.
Power supply parameters:
Input: 190-260 VAC 50 Hz
Output: 24V, 3A, 72W
Fsw 65kHz, DCM, ETD39 with 0.4mm air gap, Primary turns 58, Secondary turns 6, Ipk primary 1.42A, Dmax 0.5
I calculated that the peak current on the primary side should reach 1.42A. Using the formula Ipks = Ipkp * (Np/Ns) I calculated the peak current on the secondary side to be 13.72A. Using the formula Irms = Ipk*SQRT(Dmax/3) I calculated the RMS current on the output to be 5.6A. I verified this with a simulation, which shows that my calculations should be correct, except for the RMS current through the capacitors, which is only 4.47A RMS and not 5.6A RMS.
Where could the error be? Are my calculations correct? Did the designer of the reference design make a mistake by using a capacitor with a maximum RMS current of 1.5A? Or am I missing something?
Additional question, why is the capacitor according to the simulation stressed only with 4.47A RMS and not 5.6A RMS?
Thank you very much :)
(Sorry for any mistakes, my English isn't great)

Deriving the RMS current for a pulsed ramp signal is easy enough, highly applicable to the problem, and informative.
The capacitor doesn't see the ramp exactly, because zero DC flows through a capacitor by definition.  Subtracting out the baseline and repeating the integral, we get:
(spoilers as I strongly encourage doing the homework yourself!)
1. Setup
For diode current, we have the function

 $$ i_D(t) = \begin{cases} t \frac{I_\text{pk}}{DT} & 0 \le t < DT \\ 0 & DT \le t < T \\ \end{cases} $$
 for peak current \$I_\text{pk}\$, duty cycle \$0 \le D < 1\$, and period \$T\$.


2. Mean Value

 We need this, to subtract from diode current, to get the capacitor current:
 \begin{eqnarray} \hat{I_D} &=& \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T i_D(t) dt = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^{DT} t \frac{I_\text{pk}}{DT} dt = \frac{I_\text{pk}}{DT^2} \int_0^{DT} t\, dt  \\ &=& \frac{I_\text{pk}}{DT^2} \left[ \frac{t^2}{2} \right]_0^{DT} = \frac{I_\text{pk}}{DT^2} \left[ \frac{(DT)^2}{2} - \frac{0}{2}\right] \\ &=& \frac{I_\text{pk} D}{2} \end{eqnarray}

3. Root Mean Square

 \begin{eqnarray} {I_\text{rms}}^2 T &=& \int_0^{T} i_C(t)^2 dt \\ &=& \int_0^{DT} \left( \frac{t I_\text{pk}}{DT} - \frac{I_\text{pk} D}{2} \right)^2 dt + \int_{DT}^{T} \left( -\frac{I_\text{pk} D}{2} \right)^2 dt \\ \end{eqnarray}


 Distribute and integrate term by term; take common constants outside:


 \begin{eqnarray} {I_\text{rms}}^2 T &=& {I_\text{pk}}^2 \int_0^{DT} \left( \frac{t^2}{D^2 T^2} - \frac{2t}{2T} + \frac{D^2}{4} \right) dt + \frac{{I_\text{pk}}^2 D^2}{4} \int_{DT}^{T} dt \\ \frac{{I_\text{rms}}^2 T}{{I_\text{pk}}^2} &=&  \left[ \frac{t^3}{3 D^2 T^2} - \frac{t^2}{2T} + \frac{t D^2}{4} \right]_0^{DT} + \frac{D^2}{4} \left[ \vphantom{\frac{1}{1}} t \right]_{DT}^{T} \\ &=&  \frac{(DT)^3}{3 D^2 T^2} - \frac{(DT)^2}{2T} + \frac{(DT) D^2}{4} - 0 + \frac{D^2 (T - DT)}{4} \\ &=&  \frac{DT}{3} - \frac{D^2T}{2} + \frac{D^3 T}{4} + \frac{D^2 T}{4} - \frac{D^3T}{4} \\ &=& DT \left( \frac{1}{3} - \frac{D}{4} \right) \\ I_\text{rms} &=& I_\text{pk} \sqrt{D \left( \frac{1}{3} - \frac{D}{4} \right) } \\ \end{eqnarray}

Since you have \$D\$ = 0.5 and \$I_\text{pk}\$ = 13.73A, \$I_\text{rms}\$ = 4.43A.
As for likely capacitors:
If your ambient operating temperature is low, they can be operated modestly above ratings.  The rating arises from self-heating, at maximum internal temperature, giving some specified lifetime.  (Notice this isn't the same as maximum ambient temperature, or even case temperature; and they don't usually give RθCA or temp rise at ratings, so extrapolating ratings isn't the most straightforward, unfortunately!  Observationally at least, the temp rise at ratings is modest, say 40°C.)
If you can add slope compensation to the controller, mild CCM will be acceptable, for stable operation.
Consider looking at aluminum polymer capacitors, which offer much higher ripple ratings / lower ESR in much smaller values.  A few 100 uF might be sufficient here, and then some additional bulk electrolytic (needing much lower ripple rating) can be used to make up the total (whatever the voltage regulation loop requires).

Hi @Tim, thank you very much for your reply. I'm not that mathematically proficient. I don't understand why the RMS current flowing out of the transformer output is not the same as the one flowing into the capacitor. It matches the formula you derived and the simulation, but I don't understand the reason behind it. Can you explain it to me? As for the capacitors, it's a closed adapter, so the temperature will be relatively high. I'll try those polymer capacitors. Thanks again and have a nice day.

Well, reasoning is as above -- the capacitor simply doesn't pass DC, so its waveform is different at the very least.  I don't know what kind or level of explanation you would find sufficient, so I went with the accurate (if technical) route above.  Perhaps it helps to note that, since RMS is sensitive to the square of the waveform, tall peaks are weighted much more heavily than modest values are, and by shifting the baseline, an average value is introduced elsewhere, but the peaks are reduced by as much, thus the RMS total can decrease, to a point anyway.
